# Possibility of escaping from a point/within a region of a vector field by following the flow

Tags: vector-fields

I am not sure if there's a single answer to my questions:

1. How can I find out if it's possible to escape from a point of a vector field by following the flow? There's a sub condition: It's not sufficient that the field is 0 at that point, but all surrounding vectors have to be 0 as well or to point inwards - like a stable equilibrium.
2. How can the same be done for a point that lies inside a region or on a region that possibly can't be left?

Is there a simple way to calculate the region of confinement?

Perhaps of relevance: All values are real and the problem is 3n-dimensional.

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: A simple example would be f(x,y)=(-1-x+x²,1-y).
I think it could be possible to find such points with the conditions f(x,y)=(0,0) & $(\partial_x f(x,y))_x<0$ & $(\partial_y f(x,y))_y<0$. In this example the sought point is $(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right),1)$. But that does not look nice.
Plot of the example:
[example flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXBaN.png)

Comment: I think you'd just look at the second partial derivatives, no? In the same way you'd determine whether a critical point is a min or a max in 2 dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand this. I added an example. If I take the second derivative of it, I get constant values (2,0).

Comment: When you say `f(x,y)=(0,0)` do you mean to find where the partial derivatives are zero? (which I think is nowhere since the partial of 1-y is -1, which is never zero)

Comment: No, by this I mean that the vector field vanishes. My try is to reverse the question: First determine whether a point has vanishing flow (vector is (0,0)), because only such points can not be left with the flow. And second to test if that point is stable by testing the flow direction if every dimension - vectors point towards the tested point. But I am not sure about that.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. Because this is a vector field, it's like a first derivative already. In this case, you'd take the first partials of the vector field and show they are negative in each direction, meaning any movement by the particle would be pushed in the opposite direction (ie, the first partials are becoming negative in the positive direction)

Comment: Good, thanks! Do I still need the condition that the vector is of length 0 at the tested point? I think so because a negative derivative does not mean the vector points in negative direction.